# Regex to match and copy up to but not including last occurrence of a particular value

Tags: regex, ksh

In one regex ksh line I need to:

1. look for the occurrence of a particular string followed by any number of characters up to the last occurrence of a particular value (in this case a comma),
2. copy the stuff matched to the output, and then
3. insert a new value after the copied text and before the last occurrence of the particular value (in this case a comma)

So, if my input string looked like this:

```
SEARCH_STRING anything_else(foo,bar),
```

What I'd like to output is this:

```
SEARCH_STRING anything_else(foo,bar) INSERTED_VALUE,
```

So far, my sed expression looks like this (which only matches and copies everything up to the first occurrence of the comma, not up to the last):

```
sed -e 's/SEARCH_STRING [^,]\+/& INSERTED_VALUE/'
```

...which results in this:

```
SEARCH_STRING anything_else(foo INSERTED_VALUE,bar)
```

...which is not quite right. I know I need to use something like a negative look ahead - but can't quite get the syntax right. Any advice you could offer would be greatly appreciated, thanks. I also need to do the same replacement incidentally at the end of the line even if the comma isn't found as well please (although I appreciate that may require a separate question and expression). Thanks in advance for any advice offered....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$` special character to match the end of the line, and the `.` special character to match the last character before that:

```
sed 's/\(SEARCH_STRING .*\)\(.\)$/\1INSERTED_VALUE\2/'
```

You could replace the final dot in the match expression with a comma if you know that this is always going to be the character you want to replace. If that last character varies, then using dot will match any such character. One downside, however, is that it also matches whitespace, so if your line has a few extra spaces after the comma, this expression will delete a space, not the comma.

To replace the last *non-whitespace* character, use this expression instead:

```
sed 's/\(SEARCH_STRING .*\)\(\S\s*\)$/\1INSERTED_VALUE\2/'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Thomas. It's a great idea, but the only problem is it loses that crucial last character (which I would like to preserve after INSERTED_VALUE). The output this produces is:    SEARCH_STRING anything_else(foo,bar INSERTED_VALUE if there is no comma at the end of the line

Comment: Oh, I see. I missed that part of your question. Now fixed.

Comment: Thomas, that's fantastic - thanks. For extra bonus points, is there any way that I can make the INSERTED_VALUE occur *after* the last character if it's not a comma, please (I appreciate that's *not* what I asked for originally)?

Comment: I would probably do that in two passes: one that matches with the last character being a comma, and one for all characters except a comma. In the first case you do as above, in the second case you simply append the INSERTED VALUE. Just play with the character class before `$` (the one inside the quoted parentheses) and the position of `\2` in the replacement.

Comment: Thanks man, I was hoping we could use a look around operator or something to avoid 2 passes. Nevertheless, kudos++

Comment: Note that you can still do it in one line though if you use pipes.

Comment: Here's a one-pass version: `sed 's/\(SEARCH_STRING .*\)\(\(,\)\|\([^,]\)\)\s*$/\1\4INSERTED_VALUE\3/'`

Comment: That is a thing of beauty! Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to use a lookahead `SEARCH_STRING .*(?=,)` but sed does not support this, instead you can do something like this:

```
sed -e 's/\(SEARCH_STRING .*\)\(,.*\)/\1 INSERTED_VALUE\2/'
```

Basically we make a backreference what comes before and after the last comma, and then piece back it together with `INSERTED_VALUE` in the middle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion rvalvik. I understand what you're trying to do here and it makes perfect sense, but unfortunately it doesn't work if there's no comma at the end of the line (and produces the same output as above when this happens)

Comment: Your original question states that you want to insert the new value after the last occurrence of a particular value, a comma. If you remove the one at the end then the last comma is the one after `foo`, so that sounds about right to me?

**Edit:**
Seems I didn't quite read all of it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking is possible if you want it to match the last comma, but only if it's the "right last comma". You'd need to match something else then :/

Comment: Yes, I appreciate it's a bit tricky. To be fair, I want it to match up to but not including either the last comma, or the last character that's not a comma (the last comma is always the "right" one). And the new value always goes before the thing that's matched. Thanks again though for your help.